# Finding the number of integers in the range (a,b) which are smaller than the numbers in the range (c,d)

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are four numbers given (let: a, b, c, d) We have to find the numbers of integers between (a,b) which are smaller than (c,d).

What will be the most efficient method to solve this problem ?

a,b,c,d are positive integers.

we have to find that how many numbers are there between a and b which is smaller than the numbers present between c and d.

Input:
1
2 3 3 4

Output:
3

Input:
1
2 999999 1 1000000

Output:
499998500001

Simple searching gives Time Limit Exceed.

Simple searching code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a,b,c,testCases,d;
cin >> testCases;
while(testCases--)
{
    int count=0;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        for(int j=c;j<=d;j++)
        {
            if(j>i)
                count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

This code gives "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED" message.
We have to reduce it's time complexity.

Comment: If `d` is always(?) larger than `c`, why need `d` at all? Any number in the set `(a, b)` that is larger than `d`, will already be larger than `c`.

Comment: I don't see the need for all these loops; as far as I can tell, this is calculation that can (and probably should) be done with pen and paper.

Comment: Ya , there is no restriction on any numbers, any number can be larger than any other number, and prints the required result.

Comment: May you post the original online judge link

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/LTIME40/problems/LTM40AB/

Comment: This question is from a old contest.

Comment: ...that's not the problem described here!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is just

```
max(0, min(b, c) - a)
```

You don't need all the loops.

- If b < c, then each number in a .. b is smaller
- If a < c < b, then each number in a .. c is smaller
- If c < a, then no number is smaller

Answer (score 1):

Possibly looking for the solution to https://www.codechef.com/LTIME40/problems/LTM40AB

The real trick behind lies in the size of the input given to you. This could be done in O(n) for the given passage time. This solution worked for me in C++ 4.8.

Let's look for all the numbers in the range [a,b] and figure out where it lies in comparison to the range [c,d]. There can be three possibilities:

- a < c: In this case, add all numbers in the range [c,d] to the answer.
- a >=c and a < d: In this case, add (d-a) to the answer, corresponding to the range [a+1,d], because now you can choose numbers only from this range.
- a >= d: No choice available.

Alternatively, you may try to find a constant-time solution (hint: try to move the range [a,b] relative to the range [c,d] and figure out the length of the overlapping regions). There might be tricky test-cases, considering the length of the ranges.